# $scope variables reset after calling a modal directive in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, pug, angular-directive

I'm making an AngularJS app that need to handle and save all the checkbox clicked by the user in a simple array of ids. If there are elements in the array and the user press the open button, a modal appear and the user can do things. Now the problem is that when i press the close button in the modal, i don't understand why but the array with all the ids is reset and i need to reselect all the checkbox to resave all the ids.

Here is my code
**App.js**

```
app.controller("requestsCtrl",["$scope", "$rootScope", "crud", function($scope, $rootScope, crud){

$scope.selectedItemsId = [];
$scope.checkedAllActive = false;


//REQUESTS LOADER
crud.read(null,0, null).then(function(d){
    $scope.requests = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(d.data));
});


//EMIT
$scope.emit = function (emitType, action) {
    console.log($scope.selectedItemsId);
    $rootScope.$broadcast(emitType, {emitType: emitType, action: action, ids: $scope.selectedItemsId});
};

$scope.checkboxHandler = function (id) {
    $rootScope.handleCheckbox($scope.selectedItemsId, id);
};
}]);

app.directive("request", function ($rootScope, $templateCache, $compile, crud) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: { message: "=" },
    link: function ($scope, element, attr) {
        $scope.name = "request";
        $scope.ids = [];



        $scope.$on("acceptRequest", function (event, data) {

            if(data.action){
                console.log("open");
                $rootScope.InjectTemplate(element, $scope.name, $scope);
                $("#modalBackground").addClass("is-visible");
                $scope.ids = data.ids;
                $scope.setTask();
            }
            else {
                console.log("close");
                $rootScope.RemoveTemplate(element);
                $("#modalBackground").removeClass("is-visible");
                $scope.ids = [];
            }
        });


        $scope.close = function () {
            $scope.$broadcast("acceptRequest", { action: false });
        };

        $scope.setTask = function () {
            if($scope.ids.length > 0){
                crud.read($scope.ids.shift(), null, null).then(function (data, err) {
                    $scope.actualTask = new actualTask(data.data[0]);
                });
            }
            else {
                $scope.close();
            }
        };
        $scope.acceptButtonClick = function () {
            $rootScope.$broadcast("submit", {});
            if($rootScope.date){
                var objUpdate = {
                    id: $scope.actualTask._id

                };

                console.log($scope.actualTask);



            }

        };
    }
};
});

app.directive("row", function($rootScope){
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    templateUrl: "row.html",
    scope: { data: "=row", triggerController: "=change"},
    link: function($scope, element, attrs){
    }
};
});
app.run(function ($rootScope, $templateCache, $compile, crud) {
//GLOBAL VARIABLE
$rootScope.date = false;

//------------------

//HANDLE CHECKBOX
$rootScope.handleCheckbox = function (selectedIds, id) {
    var i = selectedIds.indexOf(id);
    if(i !== -1)
        selectedIds.splice(i, 1);
    else
        selectedIds.push(id);

    console.log(selectedIds);
};
//---------------


//DOWNLOAD ACTUAL TASK
$rootScope.ActualTaskOrExit = function (ids) {

    if(ids.length > 0){

        crud.read(ids.shift(), null, null).then(function (data, err) {
            console.log(data.data[0]);
            return new actualTask(data.data[0]);
        });
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
};

//---------------

//INJECT AND REMOVE TEMPLATE
$rootScope.InjectTemplate = function (element, template, $scope) {
    var template = $templateCache.get(template);
    element.html(template);
    $compile(element.contents())($scope);
};

$rootScope.RemoveTemplate = function (element) {
    element.html("");
};
//----------------------------

//DATE FUNCTIONS
$rootScope.fromUTCtoITimestamp = function (data) {
    var date = data.split('T')[0];
    var hours = data.split('T')[1].substring(0,5);

    var year = date.split('-')[0];
    var month = date.split('-')[1];
    var day = date.split('-')[2];
    var hour = hours.split(':')[0];
    var minutes = hours.split(':')[1];

    return Date.UTC(year, month, day, hour, minutes);
};
$rootScope.fromTimestampToUTC = function (data) {
    return new Date(data).toISOString();
};
//--------------------


$rootScope.getModalTemplate = function (modalType) {
    return $templateCache.get(modalType);
};

$rootScope.getDate = function (data) {
    var t = data.split('T');
    var day = t[0].split('-');
    var dateOne = day[2] + '/' + day[1] + '/' + day[0];
    var hours = t[1].split(':');
    var dateTwo = hours[0] + ":" + hours[1];
    return dateOne + " " + dateTwo;
};
});

app.service("crud", ["$http","$location", function($http, $location){
var service = this;

service.create = function(obj){
    return $http({
        method: 'PUT',
        url: "/app/create",
        data: { obj: obj }
    });
};
service.read = function (id, status, date) {
    if(id == null && status == null && date == null) return null;
    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: "/app/read",
        params: {id: id, status: status, date: date }
    });
};
service.delete = function(id){
    return $http({
        method: 'DELETE',
        url: "/app/delete",
        params: { id: id }
    });
};
service.update = function(obj, path){
    return $http({
        method: 'PUT',
        url: path == 0 ? "/app/update" : "/app/updateProfile" ,
        data: { obj: obj }
    });
};
}]);
```

**Index.jade**

```
script(type="text/ng-template" id="requests.html")
  h1="Richieste"
  div
    button(ng-click="emit('acceptRequest', true)" ).buttonModify="Accetta"
    button(ng-click="emit('removeRequest', true)" ).buttonTerminate="Rimuovi"
  table
    tr
      th
        a(ng-click="selectAll()")#selectAll.mdi.mdi-arrow-down-drop-circle.mdi-24px.mdi-light
      th="ORDINE"
      th="DISPOSITIVO"
      th="APPUNTAMENTO"
      th="CLIENTE"
    tr( ng-repeat="request in requests" id="{{ request._id }}" row="request" change="checkboxHandler")
  div#noData
    {{ requests.length == 0 ? "Nessuna Richiesta da mostrare" : ""}}

div#modalBackground
  request

script(type="text/ng-template" id="row.html")
  td
    input(type="checkbox" ng-model="check" value="{{ data._id }}" ng-change="triggerController(data._id)"  )
  td="{{ data.ordercode }}"
  td="{{ data.device }}"
  td="{{ data.appointment }}"
  td="{{ data.name + ' ' + data.surname }}"
```

Comment: Modal windows  prevent the user from accessing the rest of the program's interface until the dialog box is closed. For this reason, you should not overuse any function that creates a dialog box (or modal window).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [ng-if directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) to add and remove the modal template. The `ng-if` directive creates a child scope so that any watchers and directive bindings created by the `$compile` service can be removed by destroying the child scope. Otherwise opening and closing of the modal leaks memory with unremoved watchers.

> ### `$rootScope` exists, but it can be used for evil
>
> Scopes in AngularJS form a hierarchy, prototypically inheriting from a root scope at the top of the tree. Usually this can be ignored, since most views have a controller, and therefore a scope, of their own.
>
> Occasionally there are pieces of data that you want to make global to the whole app. For these, you can inject `$rootScope` and set values on it like any other scope. Since the scopes inherit from the root scope, these values will be available to the expressions attached to directives like `ng-show` just like values on your local `$scope`.
>
> Of course, global state sucks and **you should use `$rootScope` sparingly**, like you would (hopefully) use with global variables in any language. In particular, **don't use it for code,** only data. If you're tempted to put a function on `$rootScope`, it's almost always better to put it in a service that can be injected where it's needed, and more easily tested.
>
> Conversely, don't create a service whose only purpose in life is to store and return bits of data.
>
> [— AngularJS FAQ](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq)